# The name does not exist in the current context. Shopping cart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, model

I am following a guide to integrate PayPal into MVC 4. However, I have come upon this error "The name "Session" does not exist in the current context." & "The name "Response" does not exist in the current context."

https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal

```
protected void CheckoutBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ShoppingCart usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCart())
        {
            Session["payment_amt"] = usersShoppingCart.GetTotal();
        }
        Response.Redirect("Checkout/CheckoutStart.aspx");
    }
}
```

I have inputted the above code in my model which is linked to the checkout page.
Please enlighten me thanks. I am new to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing the System.Web namespace. Include it at the top of your class like [so](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx). If you then receive an error to the tune of 'namespace cannot be found', then you're missing the reference to System.Web.

Comment: I have "using system.web" and system.web reference in my project. I added "using system.web.ui" into the model too for ImageClickEventArgs. Thanks for your reply.